# Automate login to a site and click a button

Tags: c#

To need to login to a site, go to a particular page (eg. local router page) and click a button to do an operation(eg Connect). Since I do it almost everyday, I thought of automating it through small C# application. I don't have any idea how to do it.Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why code `C#` for one click? Try [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/).

Here is a [starter tutorial](http://www.technibble.com/automation-with-autoit-tutorial-part-2/). This will help you to quickly automate clicking on the default buttons of an application. Some more tricks from AutoIt and you will be able to do almost anything you can tell someone over the phone to do on the GUI.

AutoIt is a useful tool to keep handy if you are working with GUI testing or were dreaming of scripting a lot of routine GUI activity.

Comment: Very similar to AutoIt is also AutoHotKey which would allow you to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the content of the HTTP-request using a tool like Fiddler. With this information you can build an application that executes these HTTP-requests.

Answer (score 1):

Trace the HTTP requests your sending using

- a browser plugin (Firebug, httpwatch, tamperdata, etc.)
- a web debugging proxy (fiddler, charles, etc.)
- a packet sniffer (wireshark, etc.)

And then use the classes in the `System.Net` namespace (e.g. [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)) to execute the same requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/), which is a FireFox plugin that allows you to record macro like scripts for playback in the browser. It is designed for automated testing of web pages, but you can export the script in C#, which can in turn be run from a console app.

If you plan to run it as a C# app, you will also need to look at [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).

Happy scripting :)

Answer (score 1):

I have created app in C# which uses the WebBrowser control provided by Microsoft
and used it to ope a website and tried to manipulate it's html and tried to put values in 
some text boxes and tried to hit the button it works for me ,hope it's helps for you as well
Sample code is as follow

```
internal void LoginToSite()
        {
            WebBrowser.Navigate("some site login Page");
            _Processing = true;
            var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
            var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
            while (_Processing)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                if (WebBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete || WebBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive)
                {
                    var htmlDocument = this.WebBrowser.Document;
                    if (htmlDocument != null)
                    {
                        foreach (HtmlElement tag in htmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                        {
                            switch (tag.Name)
                            {
                                case "username":
                                    tag.InnerText = username;
                                    break;
                                case "password":
                                    tag.InnerText = password;
                                    break;
                                case "cmdlogin":
                                    tag.RaiseEvent("onclick");
                                    tag.InvokeMember("Click");
                                    break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    _Processing = false;
                }
            }
        }
```